# How to have an array point to an already initialized data type? Java/Android

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, store

Sorry I don't know how to phrase this question.
I know a way to solve my problem currently I was wondering if I could make it better.

Is it possible to make an array point to an already initialized data type?

```
String matt ="";
String tom ="";
String id ="";

String[] ar = {"id", "matt", "tom"};
ar[0]="hi";
```

//////////////////////
how can I make this: 
`ar[0]="hi";` 
equal this:

```
id="hi";
```

/////////////////////
or can I do something like this?

```
String[] ar = {String id ="", String matt ="", String tom =""};
```

///////original code/////////

```
        String matt ="";
    String tom ="";
    String id ="";
    String[] ar = {"id", "matt", "tom"};


    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {  // i indexes each element successively.
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ar[i]+":(\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        if (m.find()) {
            data=data+"\nfound: "+ar[i]+" "+m.group(1).toString();
            ar[i]= m.group(1).toString();   
        }
    }
    data=data+"\nvaribale: "+ id;

    tv.setText(data);
```

Comment: You can't; what are you actually trying to do? It looks like you want to parse some text that looks (in part) like "tom:23" and set the value of tom to 23? In that case, you want a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (such as [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)), not an array.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want to store the field names in the array, and have the loop assign the results to the corresponding fields? You could do that with Java reflection (or helper libraries like BeanUtils), but I would stay away from that. One alternative option is to use a Map instead of the fields. `map.put(ar[i], m.group(1).toString());`

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you can only try something like this:

```
public class StringWrapper {
    public String value;

    public StringWrapper(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }   
}
```

And use it like so:

```
StringWrapper id = new StringWrapper("id");
StringWrapper tom = new StringWrapper("tom");
StringWrapper matt = new StringWrapper("matt");

StringWrapper[] objs = new StringWrapper[] {id, tom, matt};

for(StringWrapper i : objs) {
    System.out.println(i.value);
}

objs[1].value = "Doge";

System.out.println(tom.value); // Doge
```

To make it better, you should also add `toString()`, `hashcode()` and `equals()`. And perhaps shorter name than what I used.

Comment: no. I want change the value stored in "matt" when I target ar[1].

Comment: You can't, since String is immutable. You'd have to make some string wrapper, and keep the value in that.

Comment: can you elaborate on a string wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

#### You can't do what you want for many reasons.

1. You can't refer to variables by name, not without lots of hideous reflection code.
2. Strings are immutable in Java so eve if you could get a variable by name, you could not change the value of the String with the indirection you want.

Comment: Thank You. My friend always tell me I look for stuff that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create a method like this one for updating your array and updating the element. Its too basic code - its just meant to give you an idea of the possible method to do that.

```
public class RandomStuff {
    private static String matt = "";
    private static String tom = "";
    private static String id = "";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String[] ar = { "id", "matt", "tom" };
        updateAr(0, "hi", ar);
        System.out.println("matt:" + matt);
    }

    public static void updateAr(final int index, final String val, final String[] ar) {
        ar[index] = val;
        if (index == 0) {
            matt = val;
        }
        if (index == 1) {
            tom = val;
        }
        if (index == 2) {
            id = val;
        }
    }
}
```